# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.This LoginScreenWidget can not be marked, as framwork is already in the process of building widgets

Tags: flutter

I have been facing this error when i am using **"AutovalidateMode"** inside **Form**.
When i press login button, it is showing this specific error. and also i could not use autovalidate inside form as it is already depricated from flutter 2.0.4.
Here is my code...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();

  AutovalidateMode _autoValidate = AutovalidateMode.disabled;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      bottomNavigationBar: getBottomNavbar(context),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidateMode: _autoValidate,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              CustomTextFieldWidget(
                controller: _emailController,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    setState(() {
                      emailValidate = true;
                    });
                    return 'Please Enter E-mail';
                  } else if (!_emailController.text
                      .contains(EmailValidator.regex)) {
                    setState(() {
                      emailValidate = true;
                    });
                    return 'Enter valid email !';
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      emailValidate = true;
                    });
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                hintValue: "Email",
                prefixIcon: "assets/image/profile/mail.png",
                iserror: emailValidate,
                textCallback: (String value) {
                  if (_autoValidate == AutovalidateMode.always)
                    _formKey.currentState.validate();
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  getBottomNavbar(BuildContext context) {
    return AppButton.flat(
      fitWidth: true,
      onTap: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          setState(() {
            loading = true;
          });
          loginCall();
        } else {
          _autoValidate = AutovalidateMode.always;
        }
      },
      text: "Login",
      textColor: Colors.black,
      backgroundColor: primaryColor,
    );
  }
}
```

**I have tried other stackoverflow answers but it won't workout for me.**

Answer (score 1):

try to toggle the form autovalidate value based on your Boolean like this

```
 child: Form(key: _formKey,
             autovalidateMode: _autoValidate ? AutovalidateMode.always : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro, but if i use boolean then actually i don't need to set autovalidateMode at all. I can put condition according to boolean inside validator directly right!

Comment: you will have to handle logic then for every form field !

Answer (score 0):

Calling setState isnt insde a validator isnt right,You are getting that error because setState is being called while the build function isnt finished or is yet painting the widgets on the screen, I would recommend you to expose onChanged method of the textfield and do the validation part there,the validator function should return a String containing an error message if input is invalid.And If there are no errors, the validator must return null.

```
CustomTextFieldWidget(
    controller: _emailController,
    onChanged:(value){
     if (value.isEmpty || !_emailController.text.contains(EmailValidator.regex)) {
        setState(() {
          emailValidate = true;
        });
     }else{
         setState(() {
           emailValidate = true;
         });
      }
    },
    validator: (value) {
      if(value.isEmpty) {
         return 'Please Enter E-mail';
      } else if (!_emailController.text.contains(EmailValidator.regex)) {
                    return 'Enter valid email !';
      } else {
          return null;
      }
    },
    type: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
    hintValue: "Email",
    prefixIcon: "assets/image/profile/mail.png",
    iserror: emailValidate,
    textCallback: (String value) {
       if (_autoValidate == AutovalidateMode.always)
          _formKey.currentState.validate();
       },
   ),
```